# Firebase Database Query orders function is not working

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I've just added the Facebook login function to my firebase app. To add some additional information when the user logs in the first time, I added a control function. To secure that the user doesn't enter the register form everytime he logs in with his Facebook account I want to check if he has already added some additional information on that register form or not.

To do so, I decided to check if his UID is already saved within the FIRDatabase. Because if you log in with Facebook you just create an FIRAUth and no reference on the FIRDATAbase. However this function does not work.

The function always returns, that there is already a reference in the FIRDatabase which is not true.

```
func checkIfUserIsregistered() {
    print("function is called")
    if FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid == nil{

        perform(#selector(handlelogout), with: nil, afterDelay: 0)

    }else{
        print("Kontrolle wird ausgeführt")
        let FirebaseUID = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid
        let UIDCheck = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
        UIDCheck.queryOrdered(byChild: "users").queryEqual(toValue: FirebaseUID).observe(.value, with: { snapshot in

            if snapshot.value == nil {
                print("User hat noch keine Datenbankreferenz")
                let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FBRegister")
                self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

            }else {
                print("Der User hat bereits eine Datenbankreferenz")

                let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "usersVC")
                self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        })

    }
}
```

Does anyone has an idea how to fix this?

Comment: is your structure like dataRef -> users -> uid_FirebaseAuthValue ?

Comment: Yes, I've just fixed it, I just had to add a ! after snapshot.value in the if clause. The snapshot value is type any?. So if I call the snapshot value it gives back an optional Null, which is not == nil. SO it calls the else clause. Now that I am looking for snapshot.value! it just calls the else clause if the snapshot value is != nil and not nil or optional nil.